# How to replace special quotes with straight quotes C++

Tags: c++, xcode, csv, parsing

For example the file I am parsing contains unicode char u201d ie. ” (accented quote)

How do I replace it with " (Straight quote)?

Comment: Iterate over the string, find the relevant marks and replace them with what you prefer as a replacement? It's kind of hard to be more specific without seeing what kind of code you have for doing this - there are a few different ways to encode strings in the first place - wide chars, utf, and so on, that would affect how you'd write the code, and several ways to have strings in C++ (`std::string`, `char *`, etc) that would also affect how you actually solve this.

Answer (score 0):

using c++ and STL i would use a code like this, you still need to save to output buffer to file.. tested on linux.

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

// load file data
char* load_file(const char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!fp)
        return NULL;

    size_t size;
    if ((0 != fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END)) || (-1 == (size = ftell(fp))))
        size = 0;

    // set fp at file start
    fseek(fp, 0, 0);

    char *buffer;
    buffer = (char*) malloc(size);
    if(!buffer)
    {
        fclose (fp);
        return NULL;
    }

    if(size != fread(buffer, 1, size, fp))
    {
        free (buffer);
        buffer = NULL;
    }

    fclose (fp);
    return buffer;
}

// replace string
std::string replace(const std::string& str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to)
{
    if(str.size() < 1)
        return str;

    std::string temp_str(str);

    size_t start_pos = 0;
    while((start_pos = temp_str.find(from, start_pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        temp_str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
        start_pos += to.length();
    }

    return temp_str.c_str();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const char* file_name = "test.txt";

    char* file_bytes = load_file(file_name);

    if(file_bytes == nullptr)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    std::cout << replace(file_bytes, "”", "\"") << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: It is not working for me, the build doesnt have any errors, but when I compile I get an undefined symbol error.

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "replace(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      genCSV() in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: it looks like you have a diferent implementation for std::string library you should review, the methods you have avaliable in your platform and edit the line : temp_str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);